# Dropdown with absoulute positioning is covered by following element

Tags: css, css-position

I have a dropdown with absolut positioning being covered by the following element. I have limited access to the HTML but can change the CSS.
I want the dropdown **div.esri-menu** to cover the **div.row-2 column-1**. How can I achieve this by changing the CSS Code?

I have tried different positioning values and using the z-index, but did not succeed.

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdanQ.png)

[Covering Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjG2l.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**div.esri-menu** has a position: absolute but it's related to the closest parent with a position different than 'static'. Which container is that?

On the other hand **div.esri-menu** and **div.row-2.column-1** belong to different containers.

The answer is about positioning the two containers **div.row-1.column-1-3** and **div.row-2.column-1**.

Try giving **div.row-1.column-1-3** a 'relative' position. That should help.